# Elementwise multiplication with pytorch weights

Tags: pytorch, elementwise-operations, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to build a simple "neural network" with just elementwise multiplication with weights.
Just for this scenario I have a data with 5 features which only one is "1" and all the rest are "0" (one hot encoded), and I am trying to predict with softmax and cross entropy loss the correct class.
Here is my code (say I have 26 features and (classes):

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.weights = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(n))

    def forward(self, x):
        return F.softmax(x * self.weights)

net = Net(n=26)
```

now I try to give the unsquized tensor data (say batch size is one) which has shape of `(1,1,26)` and the tensor labels with shape of `(1,26)`.
When I insert to the loss function by using `loss = criterion(nn_outputs, labels)` and receive the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.  at c:\a\w\1\s\tmp_conda_3.7_110509\conda\conda-bld\pytorch_1544094576194\work\aten\src\thnn\generic/SpatialClassNLLCriterion.c:110
```

Maybe there is a more simple way to build and train this simple neural network without errors?

Comment: Can you add the loss part? It seems that your target classes are one-hot, but as much I remember cross-entropy loss that class ids

Comment: @UmangGupta When I use the loss with the class ids I receive the error 'RuntimeError: dimension specified as 0 but tensor has no dimensions'

Comment: Can you try and print dimension of tensors input to cross-entropy loss?

Comment: @UmangGupta The input shape is 'torch.Size([1, 1, 26])' and output (which is scalar) is 'tensor(0)'

Comment: make the output of forward as `[1,26]` size and make the scaler as size [1].

Comment: what do you mean by making the forward output to be as this shape? can you share the code please?

Comment: `output=F.softmax(x * self.weights); return output.view([1,26])`